# NEO4J - ERROR Failed to generate JSON output. java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms

Tags: python, rest, neo4j

I'm running some time-consuming queries from py over rest on neo4j and I get the "Idle timeout expired..."

PY:
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=(username, password), verify=False, timeout=300000)

NEO4JCONF:
dbms.rest.transaction.idle_timeout=30000000

Queries are run in parallel using threads. The weird thing is that they run fine when executed one by one. Is there some other timeout that I need to set in neo4j.

Thanks!

Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: 2020-08-25 07:32:55.764+0000 ERROR Failed to generate JSON output. java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:235)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:226)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:524)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.write(WebComponent.java:300)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:135)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService$InterruptingOutputStream.write(TransactionalService.java:287)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator._flushBuffer(Utf8Generator.java:1754)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator.flush(Utf8Generator.java:1088)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1615)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.Neo4jJsonCodec.writeValue(Neo4jJsonCodec.java:148)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonGeneratorBase.writeObject(JsonGeneratorBase.java:314)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.RowWriter.write(RowWriter.java:39)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.ExecutionResultSerializer.lambda$writeRows$0(ExecutionResultSerializer.java:453)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_5.runtime.executionplan.StandardInternalExecutionResult$$anon$4.visit(StandardInternalExecutionResult.scala:178)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.runtime.RuntimeJavaValueConverter$feedQueryResultRecordIteratorToVisitable.accept(RuntimeJavaValueConverter.scala:65)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_5.runtime.PipeExecutionResult.accept(PipeExecutionResult.scala:74)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_5.runtime.executionplan.StandardInternalExecutionResult.accept(StandardInternalExecutionResult.scala:192)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_5.runtime.executionplan.StandardInternalExecutionResult.accept(StandardInternalExecutionResult.scala:170)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ClosingExecutionResult$$anonfun$accept$1.apply$mcV$sp(ClosingExecutionResult.scala:153)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ClosingExecutionResult$$anonfun$accept$1.apply(ClosingExecutionResult.scala:153)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ClosingExecutionResult$$anonfun$accept$1.apply(ClosingExecutionResult.scala:153)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ClosingExecutionResult$$anonfun$safelyAndClose$1.apply(ClosingExecutionResult.scala:171)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.exceptionHandler$runSafely$.apply(exceptionHandler.scala:89)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ClosingExecutionResult.safelyAndClose(ClosingExecutionResult.scala:174)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ClosingExecutionResult.accept(ClosingExecutionResult.scala:152)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.javacompat.ExecutionResult.accept(ExecutionResult.java:313)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.ExecutionResultSerializer.writeRows(ExecutionResultSerializer.java:446)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.ExecutionResultSerializer.statementResult(ExecutionResultSerializer.java:113)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.executeStatements(TransactionHandle.java:324)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.commit(TransactionHandle.java:157)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService.lambda$executeStatementsAndCommit$1(TransactionalService.java:204)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:71)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:57)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationEnabledFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationEnabledFilter.java:132)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:115)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:427)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:321)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:786)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:743)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: ... 1 more
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: 2020-08-25 07:32:55.767+0000 ERROR Failed to generate JSON output. Closed
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:491)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.write(WebComponent.java:300)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:135)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService$InterruptingOutputStream.write(TransactionalService.java:287)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator._flushBuffer(Utf8Generator.java:1754)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator.flush(Utf8Generator.java:1088)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1615)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.Neo4jJsonCodec.writeValue(Neo4jJsonCodec.java:148)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonGeneratorBase.writeObject(JsonGeneratorBase.java:314)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1090)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.ExecutionResultSerializer.errors(ExecutionResultSerializer.java:317)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.commit(TransactionHandle.java:177)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService.lambda$executeStatementsAndCommit$1(TransactionalService.java:204)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:71)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:57)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationEnabledFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationEnabledFilter.java:132)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:115)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:427)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:321)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:786)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:743)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: 2020-08-25 07:32:55.767+0000 ERROR Failed to generate JSON output. Closed
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:491)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent$Writer.write(WebComponent.java:300)
Aug 25 10:32:55 sure1810mp1vm3 neo4j: at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse$CommittingOutputStream.write(ContainerResponse.java:135)

Comment: facing the same issue..any work around?

Comment: Yes, I reinstalled all python libs used by the script and I got the same error. The workaround is not using threads... I will go with this "no threads" option because the export time is decent

Comment: Do u mean python threads?

Comment: Yes, python threads